# Why won't beautifulsoup return all the values when i use the find_all function?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to print out the KDA ratio and the summoner name, but it prints only the first result even when I use the find_all function.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source=requests.get("https://euw.op.gg/summoner/userName=Tetetot").text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,"lxml")


for gameitems in soup.find_all("div",class_="GameItemList"):
#print(gameitems.prettify())
    name =gameitems.find("div",class_="ChampionName").a.text
    k=gameitems.find("span",class_="Kill").text
    d=gameitems.find("span",class_="Death").text
    a=gameitems.find("span",class_="Assist").text
    print(name)
    print(k,d,a,sep='/')
    print()
```

"

All the HTML in the webpage is being parsed, yet it doesn't work. This is my first time using the beautiful soup library so any help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: There is only one `<div>` with class "GameItemList" on that page.

Comment: You're also printing out the KDA and Champion name for particular games, not the summoner's overall KDA ratio and summoner name. Which were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I wanted it to print the summoner's name and the no of kills,deaths and assists separated by a /.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print chapion names and K/D/A stats, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
}

source = requests.get(
    "https://euw.op.gg/summoner/userName=Tetetot", headers=headers
).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

for c in soup.select(".GameItemList .ChampionName"):
    name = c.get_text(strip=True)
    k = c.find_next("span", class_="Kill").text
    d = c.find_next("span", class_="Death").text
    a = c.find_next("span", class_="Assist").text
    print("{:<20} K:{:<5} D:{:<5} A:{:<5}".format(name, k, d, a))
```

Prints:

```
Akali                K:2     D:11    A:4    
Akali                K:2     D:8     A:3    
Jhin                 K:2     D:8     A:4    
Ezreal               K:3     D:6     A:3    
Miss Fortune         K:11    D:10    A:7    
Akali                K:13    D:5     A:14   
Yasuo                K:2     D:3     A:11   
Jhin                 K:4     D:2     A:10   
Akali                K:1     D:6     A:3    
Akali                K:0     D:2     A:1
```

Comment: What exactly does the .select function do here if you don't mind me asking??

Comment: @VedhaSankar `soup.select(".GameItemList .ChampionName")` is using CSS selector `".GameItemList .ChampionName"` - that means select every element with `class="ChampionName"` that is inside elemement with `class="GameItemList"`